# Python: storing object in 2d array and calling its method

Tags: python

I'm trying my hand at making a chess app. Code below:

```
#file containing pieces classes
class Piece(object):`

     name = "piece"
     value = 0
     grid_name = "____"


class Pawn(Piece):

# Rules for pawns.
#If first move, then can move forward two spaces

name = "Pawn"
value = 1
grid_name = "_PN_"
first_move = True


#Main file
from Piece import *



class GameBoard:

   pieces = []
   grid = [][]

   def __init__(self):

      self.grid[1][0] = self.pieces.append(Pawn())



currentBoard = GameBoard()
```

I want to call the value variable for the object located at grid[1][0]

It would look something like:

```
 print currentBoard.grid[1][0].value
```

This code doesn't work which tells me I'm missing something regarding the scope of the objects and variables. Is this something that is possible in Python?

## EDIT - Solution

I did find a solution to this in using the grid list to hold a reference to the indexing of the objects in the pieces list. Code below:

```
class GameBoard:

    # initialize empty board
    grid = [["____" for i in range(8)] for j in range(8)]
    pieces = []

    def __init__(self):

        self.grid[0][0] = 0
        self.grid[0][1] = 1
        self.grid[0][2] = 2
        self.grid[0][3] = 3
        self.grid[0][4] = 4
        self.grid[0][5] = 5
        self.grid[0][6] = 6
        self.grid[0][7] = 7
        self.grid[1][0] = 8
        self.grid[1][1] = 9
        self.grid[1][2] = 10
        self.grid[1][3] = 11
        self.grid[1][4] = 12
        self.grid[1][5] = 13
        self.grid[1][6] = 14
        self.grid[1][7] = 15


pieces = []

pieces.append(Pawn())

#grid will return the integer which can be passed to the other list to pull an 
#object for using the .value attribute

print pieces[currentBoard.grid[1][0]].value
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? Likely, you should be encountering a `SyntaxError` here: `grid = [][]`.

Comment: For that matter, `self.grid[1][0] = self.pieces.append(Pawn())` this might also throw an error, or at the very least definitely not do what you expect. Regardless, if you have some list `grid` then you can definitely access attributes belonging to objects in the list like `grid[0][0].value`. That isn't the problem with your code. You should read up on list basics in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see what you're saying. Sorry, I left off part of the code. It breaks when trying to call that method, i already initialized the 2d list in the code on my computer. I'll update in a little bit. Sorry about that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see what you mean. I'm trying to incorporate a dynamic object in the list and then move the objects around the board as they are called. Should I leave out the pieces list?

Comment: **How** does it break? You aren't giving us sufficient information. Indeed, as written your code shouldn't make it passed the parser and it should throw a `SyntaxError` when you define your `GameBoard` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your code so that it simply runs as a single file:

```
#file containing pieces classes
class Piece(object):
     name = "piece"
     value = 0
     grid_name = "____"


class Pawn(Piece):
    # Rules for pawns.
    #If first move, then can move forward two spaces

    name = "Pawn"
    value = 1
    grid_name = "_PN_"
    first_move = True

class GameBoard:

   pieces = []
   grid = [[],[]]

   def __init__(self):

      self.grid[0][1] = self.pieces.append(Pawn())



currentBoard = GameBoard()
```

There are a few things that need to be corrected. For one, the variables defined in `Piece`, `Pawn` and `GameBoard` are not defined under the `__init__()` method. This means that these variables will be shared by all instances of the class.

Example:

```
>>> pawn1 = Pawn()  # Make two Pawns
>>> pawn2 = Pawn()
>>> print pawn1.first_move, pawn2.first_move
True, True
>>> pawn1.first_move = False  # Change the first pawns attribute
>>> print pawn1.first_move, pawn2.first_move # But both change
False, False
```

To avoid this, define your class attributes under the method `__init__()`  for all three of your classes.

Example:

```
class Pawn(Piece):
    # Rules for pawns.
    #If first move, then can move forward two spaces
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Pawn"
        self.value = 1
        self.grid_name = "_PN_"
        self.first_move = True
```

Next, your variable `grid` is not properly defined in python. If you wanted a list with two empty lists you could do the following

```
grid = [[], []]
```

But an easy way to make an 8x8 structure of empty lists would be to do the following

```
grid = [[[] for i in xrange(8)] for j in xrange(8)]
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you! Now I understand the importance of using init.